# How to change the error message like user is already register when we do task.getException()?

Tags: firebase

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(sEmail,sPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+task.getException(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
```

Like in above task.getException() will give default message with com.google.firebase... so how can i change it

Comment: Just replace task.getException() with your own message? Do you even understand that line?

Comment: Yes. task. getException() gives the error message like email badly formatted or user already registered or auth is not enabled.. So how i will come to know which error occurred...

Comment: When you say "I will come to know", do you mean the end user? Just test to figure the exception for each condition, add either a switch or if else chain for each condition to replace the message.

Comment: Yes end user.. Thanks.. I will try that option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u want to receive the message just use 
task.getException().getMessage();
this will give you only the error message nothing else.
Thank you.